# MemoryStream limits, can I go nuts?

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I'm trying to move some code that used FileStreams directly to using MemoryStreams which you can then CopyTo a FileStream *if need be*.

However, this is giving me OutOfMemory errors. Poking about here it appears that the buffer is quite small by default. The examples suggest declaring the buffer as 300k.

But my files are between 1 and 100 MB. Can I simply declare it as 100 MB?

Comment: How many files to you have opened (total and at the same time)?

Comment: One. We are reading from an XML file, modifying it, and writing it back out. However, that modification may greatly expand the size, there's no way to predict.

Comment: What kind of process is this running in? Is it a 32bit or 64bit memory space?

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from memory fragmentation. To understand the issue better, read [“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx).

Consider what the MemoryStream needs to do when it needs to grow: it needs to allocate a larger internal buffer and copy old contents into it. What's even worse is that these buffers will soon go on the Large Object Heap, which has a lot of [fragmentation issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode.aspx).

Comment: Right, so if I declare the buffer larger than the file could ever be, that will solve the problem, right?

So I declared it to be 10 MB, for a 5 MB file. I still get the error, but only when it reaches the same point in the writing process.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Only if you ever only declare one buffer, and reuse it. Obviously, than implies that you are allocating a lot of memory, possibly never to be used.

Comment: That is what I do. One file, declared once, used once. But it still gives me the error.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Please show the code where you allocate the MemoryStream.

Comment: Dim MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(10000000)

Comment: That looks like a local variable. Are you sure that this code is only ever executed once, i.e. the method in which it resides is only called once?

Comment: Yes, it is called once. A similar routine to read the file in is also called once.